# Add (part of) a string from one cell to another in the same series and iterate down entire column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this problem here. Suppose I have a data set

========================

```
       A      B      C   
  0   a;b  a;b;c  a;b;c
  1   b;c    a;b  a;b;c
  2  None    c;d    c;d
```

========================

Values in each columns are strings that include ';'. I need to check when the letters (or words) separated by ';' in column A are in column B and produce and new column C which is a compilation of the letters (no repeat) in column A and B.
I tried using 
A in B
A.isin(B)
both didn't work as the boolean was 'ambiguous'.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to process each row. See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for details.

```
def combine_words(s):
    return ';'.join(sorted(set(c for w in s for c in w.split(';') if c)))

df['C'] = df[['A', 'B']].fillna('').apply(combine_words, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you.
Where do I reference the columns though?

Comment: @JonathanMak Currently all of the columns are being used. Updated answer such that a subset are being used.

Comment: I figured that out. It's quite elegant. Thanks again.

Comment: @JonathanMak You are welcome. Just saw your other question and realize you are new to SO. If an answer(s) solves the problem you posted, please mark the (best) answer as accepted. This helps users know which questions still need to be worked on.

Comment: Just curious, I don't understand how the for loop in the set function works, would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @JonathanMak Sure. They are very similar to list comprehensions (except they use a different data structure). [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a link to how the syntax works!